# Get numbers from string - php

Tags: string, variables, get

I have this string:

> subcategory19,category1

And I want to get from it these values:

> 19
>
> 1

in two separate variables.

I tried many ways, out on the internet, but I couldn't do it with any of them.

Any idea ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You tried many ways.Please post those.

Comment: That's because you didn't care to understand them so you could tweak them for your precise use case.

Comment: The general variant, which I tried is this :
if (strpos($catvariable,'subcategory') !== false) {
   $action1 = substr($catvariable, strpos($catvariable, '/subcategory/')+11); 
   $action1_2 = substr($catvariable, strpos($catvariable, '/subcategory/')+12); 
   $subcategoryid= str_replace("$action1_2", "", "$action1");
   $category = substr($catvariable, strpos($catvariable, '/subcategory/')+21); 
   }
   if (strpos($catvariable,'subcategory') === false) {
   $category=$catvariable;
   $subcategoryid="0";
   }

Comment: It would be easier to read what you've done so far if you edit your original post to include it, rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the format to be:

> subcategory[X],category[Y]

the you use `explode` in order to split the string in two by the `,`. Then you'll have two strings in the format `subcategory[X]` and `category[Y]` which can be simplified by removing `subcategory` and `category` which will return the two numeric values in the string. At this point you just need of the `(int)` cast.

Here's an example:

```
$string; // the string
$ar = explode(',', $string);
$x = (int) str_ireplace('subcategory', '', $ar[0]);
$y = (int) str_ireplace('category', '', $ar[1]);
```

Notice that this is optimized (and don't use REGEX) but will work only with the fixed format provided above. Therefore `category12,subcategory4`, `subcategory24` or `subcategory97category90` will trigger errors.